# Send email if planned date is passed in dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, workflow, time-wait

I need to write a workflow for a library system. In which the workflow required to wait after 5 days when planned check in date is passed and then send an email. I tried the following but seems it'll not work.

```
If Planned check-in date Equals 5 DaysBook:Check Out
then send email
```

Any suggestion where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you would need to use the wait condition rather than the if condition support here.